# In Keras,already have fed a proper shape and dtype value for placeholder , why it raised an Invalid ArgumentError error ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I need to tune parameter for a CNN at the first layer ,So what i did is *made a circulation ,and each step changed hyper parameter (the parameter is the number of kernel and the size of kernel )* .then output the result to local file,including the *acc* and *loss* ,so on .

Frame is :

```
for  kernel_number , kernel_size  in   combination of all allowed kernel_numbers and kernel_size :
          make  a  CNN model 
          train model  and  write the result to local file
```

The core code is :

```
print(Y_train.shape)
#the result is (2200,11)
print(X_train.shape)
#the result is (2200,2,128,1)
for number , size in number_size:
    #model 
    inputs = Input(shape=(2, 128, 1), name='input_layer')
    inner = Convolution2D(number, size, padding='same', activation="relu", name="conv1",
                          kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(inputs)
    inner = Dropout(rate=0.5, name='drop_layer1')(inner)
    inner = Convolution2D(16, (2, 3), padding="same", activation="relu", name="conv2",
                          kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(inner)
    inner = Dropout(rate=0.5, name='dropout_layer2')(inner)
    inner = Flatten(name='flatten_layer')(inner)
    inner = Dense(256, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu", name="dense1")(inner)
    inner = Dropout(rate=0.5)(inner)
    Y_preds = Dense(11, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='softmax', name="dense2")(inner)
    model = Model(inputs, Y_preds, name='model')
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_out,metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])
    model.summary()
    #end model 
    #make dir 
    os.mkdir(dirpath.format(str(size[1]),str(number)))
    os.chdir(dirpath.format(str(size[1]),str(number)))
    os.mkdir('loss')
    os.mkdir('acc')
    os.mkdir('tensorboard')
    #make dir end 
    model.fit(X_train,Y_train,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=epochs,
              verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.2,
              callbacks = [
                    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(

                        '{val_categorical_accuracy:.4f}.hdf5',
                        monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='auto'
                    ),
                    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto'),
                    keras.callbacks.TensorBoard('/TensorBoard/tb.log',
                          write_images=True,write_grads=True,write_graph=False,histogram_freq=1
                    )
              ]
    )
    #return original dir
    os.chdir('..')
```

The log and  error were:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)     (None, 2, 128, 1)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 2, 128, 10)        50
_________________________________________________________________
drop_layer1 (Dropout)        (None, 2, 128, 10)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 2, 128, 16)        976
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_layer2 (Dropout)     (None, 2, 128, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_layer (Flatten)      (None, 4096)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 256)               1048832
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense2 (Dense)               (None, 11)                2827
=================================================================
Total params: 1,052,685
Trainable params: 1,052,685
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 1760 samples, validate on 440 samples
Epoch 1/1
1760/1760 [==============================] - 6s 4ms/step - loss: 2.3977 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0966 - val_loss: 2.3969 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1250
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)     (None, 2, 128, 1)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 2, 128, 10)        90
_________________________________________________________________
drop_layer1 (Dropout)        (None, 2, 128, 10)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 2, 128, 16)        976
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_layer2 (Dropout)     (None, 2, 128, 16)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_layer (Flatten)      (None, 4096)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 256)               1048832
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense2 (Dense)               (None, 11)                2827
=================================================================
Total params: 1,052,725
Trainable params: 1,052,725
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 1760 samples, validate on 440 samples
Epoch 1/1
1024/1760 [================>.............] - ETA: 1s - loss: 2.3980 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0723Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense2_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
         [[Node: dense2_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trian_cnn_conv1.py", line 136, in <module>
    write_images=True,write_grads=True,write_graph=False,histogram_freq=1
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1657, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 73, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py", line 778, in on_epoch_end
    result = self.sess.run([self.merged], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense2_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
         [[Node: dense2_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'dense2_target', defined at:
  File "trian_cnn_conv1.py", line 112, in <module>
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_out,metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy])
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 755, in compile
    dtype=K.dtype(self.outputs[i]))
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 497, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1599, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3090, in _placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense2_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
         [[Node: dense2_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

The most import information is the last line and was that

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense2_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
         [[Node: dense2_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

The keras and the TensorFlow i was using now is

```
In [9]: keras.__version__
Out[9]: '2.1.2'
In [10]: import tensorflow
In [12]: tensorflow.__version__
Out[12]: '1.4.0'
```

I have three  question .

1. one is what caused the error ,from the information , it said that
   *we must feed a Tensor with shape [?,?] to dense2_target  layer*, it is no *dense2_target*,where is the dense2_layer ?
2. two is ,if  the *dense2_target* is my output layer in my model .The data which is feed to is Y_train and the shape is (2200，11),it is a shape with two axis ,,so what is wrong ?
3. three is that ,if the code is wrong ,why the error triggered at the second cycle ,not the first cycle .

Additionally,the way i used to tuned the parameter is a bad way .The bad is that i must  to initialize a new model to run the network at each cycle .I ever tried to make the code easy because I know the frame of this network is same but the hyper parameter  but failed .If anyone have idea to do with it ,it also put a suggestion to me .I am very glod to see your reply .